# If difference quetions belong to a convex open set then the derivatives is also belong to that open set.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable function such that for convex open set $O\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and convex open set $A\subset U$ we have:
$\forall x,y\in A, f(x)-f(y)\in O\cdot (x-y)$
then if $x\in A$ we have $f'(x)\in O$.
Here by $O\cdot (x-y)$ we mean open interval of inner product of every member of $O$ in $x-y$.

I know this is true if $O$ is a closed set, and I try using hyperplane seperation theorem as user251257 mentioned, but it didn't work because $O$ is open set and if we seperate $f'(x)$ from $O$ we didn't get any contradiction. I also have doubt about this counterexample: if $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $A=(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $O=(-1,1)$ then $\forall x,y\in A$ we have $f(x)-f(y)\in O\cdot (x-y)$ but $f'(0)=1\notin O$.

Comment: My bad. You are right. Great counter example.